# Unable to load sqlite3 gem on Ruby 1.8.7 that is controlled by RVM

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems, rvm

I tried to load sqlite3 library in Ruby 1.8.7 that is controlled by RVM. But I can't.

Situations are following

```
watanabe@linux:~$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /home/watanabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371
watanabe@linux:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [x86_64-linux]
watanabe@linux:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
rake (10.0.4)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
watanabe@linux:~$ gem -v
1.8.25
watanabe@linux:~$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > require 'sqlite3'
LoadError: no such file to load -- sqlite3
        from (irb):1:in `require'
        from (irb):1
1.8.7 :002 > exit
watanabe@linux:~$ ls -lA .rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 watanabe watanabe 4096 Jun  5 17:02 sqlite3
-rw-r--r-- 1 watanabe watanabe  249 Jun  5 17:02 sqlite3.rb
watanabe@linux:~$ ls -lA .rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3/lib/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 watanabe watanabe 4096 Jun  5 17:37 sqlite3
```

I think that sqlite3 gems are installed correctly. But I can't load sqlite3. Do you know any solutions for this problem?

NOTE:
It works in Ruby 1.9.3.

```
watanabe@linux:~$ rvm use 1.9.3
Using /home/watanabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
watanabe@linux:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]
watanabe@linux:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
rake (10.0.4)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
watanabe@linux:~$ irb
1.9.3p429 :001 > require 'sqlite3'
 => true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8.7 you'll need to first `require 'rubygems'` and then `require 'sqlite3'`

From the [documentation](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3):

> You see, because the of versioned nature of the gems repository, RubyGems doesn’t store the library files directly in standard library search path. It adds the necessary gem packages to the library seach path as needed at run time.
>
> This means that RubyGems must be loaded before any gem libraries are accessable.
>
> **Ruby 1.9**:
>   The default Ruby 1.9 package now includes RubyGems by default on most platforms (presently Debian based systems split this out into a separate package). This means that on Ruby 1.9 and above, you will not need to require 'rubygems' in order to load gem libraries.